# Bot framework HTTP status code InternalServerError

Tags: botframework

I try to integrate bot framework with UWP application using direct line, but I have this error. I used a web chat to test, it still shows me the same error. But if I use a Bot emulator to test it, it works. I already set my published bot to *Always On* on Azure, but still have same issue:

[image][image]

Comment: So your bot code is having an issue. Next step is debugging: one easy way is to add Application Insights in your bot and see the Exception that you got, as `InternalServerError` is the generic response when the bot is having an exception. If you want more help you should add some code, like your MessageController content at least

Comment: @ Nicolas R after Debugging, I think i find the issue, can you help me to solve t?[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093272/bot-framework-bot-generates-an-error-an-http-502-response-bad-gateway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Azure portal to create a Bot service, and then copy your original code (that you program in Visual Studio), and paste it to the website editor, then click SAVE, now test your bot again, I think it can work [image]