# Chatbot working on emulator but not working on Web Chat and Direct Line after publishing to Azure

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-bot-service

When I try to deploy and test the bot on Azure I'm getting the following error in Web Chat: There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError. I also have error 502 in the browser console when I use Direct Line: https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/1Td3aCZWwMV92LyotjCNuT-eu/activities 502.

The bot works fine in the emulator.

Use: JavaScript,
Deployment Environment: Azure Bot Service.

MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword has been set correctly in the .env file.
I use Luis and Snowflake too.

Please let me know if there is any information which I can provide to help resolve my issue.

Comment: You can refer to similar issues [Bot framework "bot generates an error, an HTTP 502 response ("Bad Gateway")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093272/bot-framework-bot-generates-an-error-an-http-502-response-bad-gateway) and [BotError : Failed to send activity: bot returned an error](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/4184#issuecomment-368298853)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [tinuCoder (sanatanCoder) · GitHub](https://github.com/tinuCoder). Posting your suggestion as answer to help other community members.

To resolve this  `There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError` error:

> Make sure to update your password wherever required.

For example: WebAppBot --> Settings and App Service --> Application settings change the password

References: [BotError : Failed to send activity: bot returned an error. httpStatusCode: 500 · Issue #4184 · microsoft/botframework-sdk · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/4184#issuecomment-368298853) and [uwp - Bot framework "bot generates an error, an HTTP 502 response ("Bad Gateway") " - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093272/bot-framework-bot-generates-an-error-an-http-502-response-bad-gateway)